# Parsing SQL with bad xml namespace

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing

Hi I have the following SQL to try and parse xml and extract the "OrderNumber".  The problem i have is this xml (which i have no control over) has a wierd xml namespace.  I changed it to abc.com just for this example, but its something else.  Anyway, when that namepace is present, the T-SQL returns a null in the result.  So it doesn't play nicely with the namespace.  If I remove the namespace manually or doing a search and replace via T-SQL, it works just fine.  I guess i can just do a search and replace but that solution just bothers me.  Was wondering if anyone else nows a better way around this?  And maybe an explanation of why it doesn't like namespaces?  Would really appreciate some advice.  Thanks!

```
Declare  @Transmission xml

set  @Transmission = '<Transmission>
  <Requests>
    <SubmitOrdersRequest>
      <Orders>
        <Order xmlns="http://www.abc.com">
          <OrderNumber>123</OrderNumber>
        </Order>
      </Orders>
    </SubmitOrdersRequest>
  </Requests>
</Transmission>'

select @Transmission.value('(Transmission/Requests/SubmitOrdersRequest/Orders/Order/OrderNumber/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Children nodes inherit the namespace of the parent, unless given a namespace themselves.  you have to define namespaces using `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`, and properly qualify node names using them.

```
Declare  @Transmission xml
set  @Transmission = '<Transmission>
  <Requests>
    <SubmitOrdersRequest>
      <Orders>
        <Order xmlns="http://www.abc.com">
          <OrderNumber>123</OrderNumber>
        </Order>
      </Orders>
    </SubmitOrdersRequest>
  </Requests>
</Transmission>';

with xmlnamespaces('http://www.abc.com' as ns1)
select @Transmission.value('(Transmission/Requests/SubmitOrdersRequest/Orders/ns1:Order/ns1:OrderNumber/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
```

Note: The reason for namespaces is that names are contextual things.  `Order` can mean in your case a purchase but in another context it could mean display rack order.  The namespace gives the name more uniqueness.